# Proving an inequality involving the logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

In Ahlfors' complex analysis text he claims that:

> If $|u| < 1$ we have by power-series development
>    $$ \log \left\lvert E_h(u) \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{h+1} |u|^{h+1}+\frac{1}{h+2}|u|^{h+2}+\dots$$

where $$E_h(u)=(1-u)e^{u+\frac{1}{2}u^2+ \dots\frac{1}{h}u^h} $$

I can't see why is this inequality true. I want to use the power-series of the logarithm, but the absolute value gets in the way.

P.S. $u$ is complex and $h$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithm of the absolute value of a complex number $\neq 0$ is just the real part of the logarithm, whichever branch of the logarithm is chosen.

For $\lvert u\rvert < 1$, we can choose the principal branch, and have

$$\begin{align}
\log E_h(u) &= \left(u + \frac12u^2 + \dotsb \frac{1}{h}u^h\right) + \log (1-u)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^h \frac{u^k}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k}\\
&= -\sum_{k=h+1}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k}.
\end{align}$$

Now estimate the real part by the absolute value to get

$$\log \lvert E_h(u)\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=h+1}^\infty \frac{\lvert u\rvert^k}{k}.$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but how can you justify the "log of product equals sum of logs" part in the first equation?

Comment: The exponential of the right hand side is $E_h(u)$. So the RHS is _one_ value of $\log E_h(u)$. The imaginary part of the RHS is smaller than $2\pi$ in absolute value in a neighbourhood of $0$, and since we chose the principal branch, the same is true for the LHS. Both sides agree in a neighbourhood of $0$, hence by the identity theorem, in the connected component of $0$ in the intersection of their domains of definition.

Comment: I believe that the principal branch has its argument lesser than $\pi$ in absolute value, rather than $2\pi$. Is your argument still valid in that case?

Comment: Ah, right, typo. The exact bound is not important, what we need is actually that both sides take the value $0$ for $u = 0$. The properties of the logarithm then guarantee that the two sides are identical in the component. The difference of both sides is smaller than $2\pi$ (not a typo here ;) in absolute value in a neighbourhood of $0$ by continuity, hence it must be $\equiv 0$ in that neighbourhood.